# Switch statement that directly takes function call as parameter

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
int count()
{
   return 5;
}

int variable = count();

switch(variable)
{
} //this works correct

switch(count())
{
}//this also works correct.
```

But which of these is the correct approach and what are the performance comparisons between the two? 
Do switch statements always have to take only a parameter?

Comment: It makes no difference at all.  Do whatever makes for the most readable code.

Comment: Second one is better because the code will be more readable. But if you are going to use it again in the code somewhere it is better to save the result so you don't calculate it again.

Comment: what do you mean by an explicit parameter?

Comment: They're both "correct" and you will not encounter a performance difference between them in your entire life (most compilers will generate identical code). Use the one you find most readable.  (I have no idea what you mean by "explicit" parameter.)

Comment: Thanks for the replies.@zEro Sorry it should have been just "parameter".

Comment: Why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

**But which of these is the correct approach**

There is nothing incorrect with either approach. `switch(count())` is simply more concise than `switch(variable)`.

Declaring a variable may make the code more readable e.g.

```
final int month = Integer.parseInt(dateMonthYearString.split("/")[1]);
switch(month){/*...*/}
```

**what are the performance comparisons between the two?**

I doubt there would be any difference in performance. Certainly not something worth worrying about.

**Do switch statements always have to take only an explicit parameter?**

I'm not sure what you mean. The expression in the `switch` statement must evaluate to  `int`, `short`, `byte`, `char` or an `enum`. From Java 1.7, the expression may also return a `String`.

Comment: Strings can be used starting in Java 7.  Switches can also operate on an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

The last statement is better as the count() is called only once.

In OOP, you can avoid using switch in some cases with design pattern State, for better performance than those two. "Replace switch/case with polymorphism" is a technique for your references.